# AnyLogic: Distribution by enter block depending on capacities in three resources

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have created multiple instances of a resource and filled them with specific delay and queue blocks. At the start of the resource I set a restricted area to check how many agents are in the resource.

[image: Screenshot Model]

My goal is to distribute incoming agents in queue1 first to resource1 until it contains 50 agents. These 50 agents are then in resource1 and are in longer delay blocks. After that resource2 should be filled until there are 50 agents in it, then resource3 and so on (theoretically still scalable upwards, but for now only for three).

The agents all arrive in time. There is a **priority that first one resource is filled completely, then the next one**.
For this I have written a function, which is regularly updated in the event.
My problem is that I don't how to make such distributions based on more and more arriving agents and additionally consider the capacities of each resource.

[image: Screenshot Function Code]

Unfortunately, since all conditions are true at the beginning and thus all if queries are true, an error is thrown. Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the code as below:

```
if (resource1.restrictedAS.entitiesInside() < 50) {
    ...
} else if (resource2.restrictedAS.entitiesInside() < 50) {
    ...
} else if (resource3.restrictedAS.entitiesInside() < 50) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin! But in this case I get an error that my agent was not able to leave one enter port. If I turn off forced pushing in all my enters it works perfectly. So would you recommend to leave forced pushing off or do I have to think of something new?

Comment: This depends on the real system, impossible to tell you. Understand why you get that error, understand the real system and then decide if forced pushing is realistic or not. If not, you need to think about changing the logic